# the default option of NDSolve

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

How should I find out what the default value of Accuracy and Precision is in the NDSolve? 
I have a pde that when I asked it to solve for me the equation with a special Accuracy and precision it gave me back an error, but if I live the NDSolve with its default. It would solve it. I don't know how to find the value of accuracy and precision.
another basic question which have is about the meaning of the Accuracy and precision. I know the meaning in general from high school, but the problem is that I do not know the meaning of Accuracy->15, does it calculate it for 15 decimal number or what?

Comment: You can do `Options[NDSolve]` and see the default values. It says `Automatic` for some. Then go to each and looks at its help. For `Accuracy` it says `AccuracyGoal->Automatic normally yields an accuracy goal equal to half the setting for WorkingPrecision` and for `PrecisionGoal` it says `->Automatic normally yields a precision goal equal to half the setting for WorkingPrecision` SO they depend on setting for `WorkingPrecision` Then you look at help for `WorkingPrecision`

Answer (score 3):

Following @Nasser's comment, both defaults are `$MachinePrecision/2`, 7.97729 in my case.

Related post: [Is manual adjustment of AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal useless?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871)